# How to get dataview object for the dataview which is already exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid, dataview

Basically I want to insert some data into existing slickgrid dataview as

```
dataView.addItem();
```

So, I need dataview object for my slickgrid dataview in the div **#myGrid**

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection ;
        SqlCommand command ;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataView dv ;
        string sql = null;
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
        sql = "Select * from product";
        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Add New");
            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();

            dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
            DataRowView newRow = dv.AddNew();
            newRow["Product_ID"] = 7;
            newRow["Product_Name"] = "Product 7";
            newRow["Product_Price"] = 111;
            newRow.EndEdit();
            dv.Sort = "product_id";


            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To find the datagrid you have to use $.find()

```
var MyGrid=$.find(<%=myGrid.ClientID%>)
```